# Como puedo realizar operaciones de calculo con datos obtenidos de un archivo .txt en C# implementando la clase StreamReader?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Como puedo realizar operaciones de calculo con datos obtenidos de un archivo .txt en C# implementando la clase `StreamReader` ?

Los datos están en forma de una tabla de empleados con sus respectivos sueldos y horas trabajadas en un archivo de texto.

Lo que requiero es que al ejecutar, el `StreamReader` en el programa muestre dicha tabla, pero con el calculo realizado a través de los datos previamente introducidos en el archivo de texto.

Comment: Depende de como esten estructurados estos datos... ¿Puedes ayudarnos aportando más información sobre tu problema? Así llamarás la atención de más personas a responder tu pregunta.

Comment: Los datos estan en forma de una tabla de empleados con sus respectivos sueldos y horas trabajadas en un archivo de texto. lo que requiero es que al ejecutar el streamreader en el programa este realice el calculo correspondiente a cada empleado

Comment: Porfavor, añade datos relevantes sobre la pregunta dando clic en el botón [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/17176/edit) al pié de esta.

Comment: De acuerdo, puede ser con un ejemplo de la estructura del archivo de texto que se desea leer en el programa?

Comment: Sí, @Ramon pero esto no quiere decir que debas quitar todo el contenido de tu pregunta.

Comment: Nombres         Tarifa por hora      Horas trabajadas
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
Elizabeth.            6.00                        40
Pedro.                 5.00                        48
Juan.                   6.50                        35
Casandra.           8.00                        50

Answer (score 1):

En principio con la clase `StreamReader` no puedes realizar ninguna oepracion de calculo ya que con esta solo leerias el archivo.

Pero si podrias volcar los datos del archivo a una clase y en esta si implementar logica para calcular que necesites

Recomendaria evalues

[filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/)

con esta podrias mapear el archivo a una clase que definas de forma simple, entonces se parsean los datos y podrias usar en los calculos

Puedes definir una clase como ser

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderID;

    public string CustomerID;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]
    public DateTime OrderDate;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")] // The decimal separator is .
    public decimal Freight;
}
```

y parsearla usando

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>();
var records = engine.ReadFile("Input.txt");

foreach (var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine(record.CustomerID);
    Console.WriteLine(record.OrderDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    Console.WriteLine(record.Freight);
}
```

como veras en el ejemplo usa las propiedades para recuperar los datos y realizar operaciones con estos